# text in table is always bold with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I have a [XML](http://pastebin.com/h5gUsT3j) and a [XSLT](http://pastebin.com/X2b0CAr9) file. 
This is my XML structure:

```
<bibliography>
    <element>
        <anotherelement>
            Some text and <italic>italic Text</italic> and <bold>bold text</bold>
        </anotherelement>
    </element>
    ...
</bibliography>
```

The structure of the output of the XML is right but somehow everything is bold in the table. How can I fix this, that only the elements with a `<bold>` tag are bold and the rest is normal?

This is how the text looks like without the table:
[image]
And with the table it suddenly look like this:
[image]

Comment: You hide the most important part from us, the XSLT...

Comment: The XSLT is linked at the beginning.

Comment: Show us the output HTML maybe? I think it might be because you are using <th> for each table cell, not <td>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put everything in `th` elements, use `td` for table data. And of course use the proper nesting for HTML tables which is `<table><tbody><tr><td>...</td></tr><!-- more tr rows here --></tbody></table>`.

Comment: Thanks. I totally don't know why I mixed up `<th>` and `<td>`.